# How could I create a dictionary with a list as key and a list as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dict in the following scenario

One list to save jobtype(s)

```
JOB_TYPE_LIST = ["PARTTIME", "FULLTIME", "WFH"]
```

Corresponding list to each jobtype

```
PARTTIME_GROUP_LIST = ["PTGroup2", "PTGroup3"]
FULLTIME_GROUP_LIST = ["FTgroup1", "FTgroup2"]
WFH_GROUP_LIST = ["WFHgroup"]
```

Expected dicts

```
dict {
    "PTGroup2": "PARTTIME",
    "PTGroup3": "PARTTIME",
    "FTgroup1": "FULLTIME",
    "FTgroup2": "FULLTIME",
    "WFHgroup": "WFH"
}
```

My current way to create this dict is do it manually.
However, I  would like to create this dict in a more pragramming way.
Otherwise, every time I add a new `jobtype` and the `corresponding list`, I need to manually modify the dict.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use dictionary instead of lists to store job types.

```
JOB_TYPES = {
    "PARTIME": ["PTGroup2", "PTGroup3"],
    "FULLTIME": ["FTgroup1", "FTgroup2"],
    "WFH": ["WFHgroup"]
}
expected_dict = {v: key for key, value in JOB_TYPES.items() for v in value}
print(expected_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'PTGroup2': 'PARTIME', 'PTGroup3': 'PARTIME', 'FTgroup1': 'FULLTIME', 'FTgroup2': 'FULLTIME', 'WFHgroup': 'WFH'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
output = {}

JOBS_MAPPING = {
    "PARTTIME": PARTTIME_GROUP_LIST,
    "FULLTIME": FULLTIME_GROUP_LIST,
    "WFH": WFH_GROUP_LIST
}


for job_label, job_group_list in JOBS_MAPPING.items():
    print(f"Job label is {job_label}, job groups list is {job_group_list}")
    for job_group in job_group_list:
        output.update({job_group: job_label})

print(ouput)
> {'PTGroup2': 'PARTTIME', 'PTGroup3': 'PARTTIME', 'FTgroup1': 'FULLTIME', 'FTgroup2': 'FULLTIME', 'WFHgroup': 'WFH'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this approach more flexible. Note that the *json* module is not required - it's just there to pretty-print the output.

Doing it this way means that you can change your list contents without having to change the code although the number of elements in the JOB_TYPE_LIST **must** match the number of other lists passed to the function.

```
import json

JOB_TYPE_LIST = ["PARTTIME", "FULLTIME", "WFH"]
PARTTIME_GROUP_LIST = ["PTGroup2", "PTGroup3"]
FULLTIME_GROUP_LIST = ["FTgroup1", "FTgroup2"]
WFH_GROUP_LIST = ["WFHgroup"]

def func(job_type_list, *args):
    dict_ = {}
    for i, jt in enumerate(job_type_list):
        for group in args[i]:
            dict_[group] = jt
    return dict_

print(json.dumps(func(JOB_TYPE_LIST, PARTTIME_GROUP_LIST, FULLTIME_GROUP_LIST, WFH_GROUP_LIST), indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "PTGroup2": "PARTTIME",
  "PTGroup3": "PARTTIME",
  "FTgroup1": "FULLTIME",
  "FTgroup2": "FULLTIME",
  "WFHgroup": "WFH"
}
```